# ¿Que devolver en un login cuando el usuario no existe o existe pero esta mal la contraseña?, usando Retrofit

Tags: android, http, retrofit, get

Buen día a todos.

Me encuentro ante la siguiente situación:

Estoy realizando un login utilizando Retrofit para las solicitudes, estas devuelven los datos del usuario cuando se loguea correctamente mediante un json.

La validación la estoy haciendo mediante php, el problema surge cuando en vez de json devuelvo un mensaje de error, por ejemplo cuando usuario o contraseña son incorrectos, retrofit me devuelve estos errores como

com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

ya que los mensajes de error so del tipo, "Contraseña incorrecta" , "Usuario no registrado"

la pregunta es: ¿como puedo recibir estos errores de login sin que retrofit me los tome como errores de mal formación de json?

Quedo atento, de antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que retrofit entiende que todo lo que reciba siempre sera un json. Para resolver el problema te recomiendo que metas los mensajes de error dentro de un json tambien.

por ejemplo:

```
{"error":401,"description":"Contraseña incorrecta"}
```

Comment: Buen día erick, despues de pensar un rato llegue a esa misma conclusión, creo que así lo voy a hacer aunque tendría que agregar estos campos en el mismo json de respuesta del login correcto, devolviendo los demás campos vacios para evitar problemas cuando retrofit parsee el json a objeto

Comment: Algunos usan modelos de respuesta de tipo {"error":{"code":401,"description":"Contraseña incorrecta"}, response:{<Modelo esperado en una respuesta correcta>}